# add or subtract from a certain date - excel

Tags: excel, date

Not sure if been asked. But questions I've seen when adding/subtracting date from referencing a cell in the formula.

I need to do it in conditional formatting for a table and need add/ subtract from a certain date. Please see attached image of what i've tried.

EDIT:
for instance, effective date example is 31/07/23
what im trying to achieve in the table is:

- RED: Less or equals to, last date of the following month, subtract 1 day (31/07/23) -1 day
- Amber: Between the dates: (01/07/23 - 30/09/23)
- Green: Greater then, 1st day after 2 months (01/09/23)

Conditional formatting formulas

[image: Conditional formatting - date formulas]

Output from my results. Issue is the Red formula is over-powering the amber/ green. Second cell date of '31/12/2024 should be green for instance based on the formulas'.

[image]

Im new to this, but learning the ropes. So please advise if my formulas not right, my order of conditional format is incorrect.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Dates are stored as a serial number, if you add 1 to that, it adds 1 day to the date. Many questions have this information as part of the answer.

Comment: I thought, EDATE adds/ subtracts a month at end to the date

Comment: 1. The example you gave is all constants- why don't you do the math yourself?  The first example is `=CellValue>=Date(2023,6,30)`.    2. Your second date range covers over the date ranges in formula 3 & 4.  They will never be green or orange.

Comment: You have not made clear what it is that you are trying to achieve or precisely where you are encountering problems.

Comment: Why do you write `EDATE(DATE(2023,7,31),-1)` instead of `DATE(2023,6,30)`?